# The correct way of getting the parent window

Tags: winapi

The MSDN says the following about the `GetParent` function:

> To obtain the parent window and not
>   the owner, instead of using `GetParent`, use `GetAncestor` with the
>   `GA_PARENT` flag.

But when calling `GetAncestor(hWnd, GA_PARENT);` for a window that doesn't have a parent, it returns the desktop window, while `GetParent` returns `NULL`.

So what is the correct way of getting a parent (and not the owner), and getting `NULL` if there are none?

Of course I could check whether `GetAncestor` returns the desktop window, but that seems like a hack to me.

Comment: The correct way is to call GetAncestor and detect the desktop.

Comment: The parent of a top-level window *is* the desktop window.  Compare with the value of GetDesktopWindow() to detect this, not exactly a hack unless you are also tinkering with multiple desktops.  This otherwise got complicated because SetParent() supports Windows 3.x programs where using the window of another process as a parent wasn't a bad idea yet.

Comment: So you say the desktop window is different for different monitors? How do I handle that?

Comment: Nope, he did not say that. He said different **desktops**. That's a rather rarely used feature of Windows that allows you to create multiple desktops per window station. These can be switched between. The most visible use of this feature is the desktop used to show  UAC dialogs.

Comment: I assume an application cannot normally temper with windows of a different desktop. Thanks for the help guys, I'm posting an answer!

Comment: P.S. what's the difference between `GetAncestor(hWnd, GA_PARENT);` and `GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HWNDPARENT);`?

Comment: Found the answer on Google. Surprisingly, GWLP_HWNDPARENT is about the owner window, not the parent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
//
// Returns the real parent window
// Same as GetParent(), but doesn't return the owner
//
HWND GetRealParent(HWND hWnd)
{
    HWND hParent;

    hParent = GetAncestor(hWnd, GA_PARENT);
    if(!hParent || hParent == GetDesktopWindow())
        return NULL;

    return hParent;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Updated in the year 2020 considering the latest Win32 documentation:

```
HWND GetRealParent(HWND hWnd)
{
    HWND hWndOwner;

    // To obtain a window's owner window, instead of using GetParent,
    // use GetWindow with the GW_OWNER flag.

    if (NULL != (hWndOwner = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_OWNER)))
        return hWndOwner;

    // Obtain the parent window and not the owner
    return GetAncestor(hWnd, GA_PARENT);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly better version that goes both "routes" and if it can't find a proper parent it will return the window itself(as to avoid null references).
Using GetParent instead of GetAncestor worked in my case and returned the window I was after.

```
    public static IntPtr GetRealParent(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        IntPtr hParent;

        hParent = GetAncestor(hWnd, GetAncestorFlags.GetParent);
        if (hParent.ToInt64() == 0 || hParent == GetDesktopWindow())
        { 
            hParent = GetParent(hWnd);
            if (hParent.ToInt64() == 0 || hParent == GetDesktopWindow())
            { 
                hParent = hWnd;
            }

        }

        return hParent;
    }
```