# Confusing: Retrieve Parent Wnd in CDialog, that is given with SetParent

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

In a `CView` derived class I give the dialog the parent via:

```
CTestDlg& dlg = m_TestDLg;
dlg.SetParent(this);
if (dlg.DoModal() != IDOK)
    return;
```

Inside `CTestDlg` I try to retrieve the parent with

```
CMyView* pTView_ = (CMyView*)GetParent();        // Wrong Parent pointer
CMyView* pTView2 = (CMyView*)GetParentOwner();   // Wrong Parent pointer  
CMyView* pTView3 = (CMyView*)m_pParentWnd;       // Wrong Parent pointer
```

I thought with `SetParent()` I can get back it with `GetParent()`.

Even the [doc in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/0x2wyab0(v=vs.140)?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(AFXWIN2%252FCWnd%253A%253AGetParent);k(CWnd%253A%253AGetParent);k(GetParent);k(DevLang-C%252B%252B);k(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue) confuses me. What really happens with `Set/GetParent()`?

Comment: Does your dialog window have the `WS_CHILD` style? Does your `CMyView` have it? I think these can play riddles with the definition of "parent".

Comment: ... IIRC, by default, popup dialogs have `WS_POPUP` but not `WS_CHILD`.

Comment: [Type Casting of MFC Class Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/type-casting-of-mfc-class-objects).

Comment: @IInspectable I want UpCast not DownCast.   But it does not matter here, because, I get wrong pointer with GetParent() & GetParentOwner() here.

Comment: @AdrianMole yes is a normal popup Dialog.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The correct way of getting the parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872126/the-correct-way-of-getting-the-parent-window)

Comment: In C++ class hierarchies, *"down"* is the direction towards more derived types. You **do** want a downcast, and none of the C-style casts are safe. Also, with MFC, you cannot tell by looking at a pointer value whether it references the window object you expected. MFC has a handle map internally that can easily cause surprising results. With that out of the way, are you trying to access the parent or owner of your window?

Comment: Ok, in future I will use C++ cast in MFC. Parent or owner? From my view, it is the same, as I excplicitly set the Parent via SetParent, And the dialog is construct in the View.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle even this gives me here the wrong parent.

Comment: Ok. Mind you I normally set the parent as part of the declaration by passing it in brackets. Eg. CDialog abc(this); I never really need to call SetParent specifically (only with modeless dialogs when the context of the parents needs to change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only child windows (WS_CHILD style set) have a parent.
For any other window style, SetOwner sets the owner window. Retrieve by calling GetOwner().

Corrected typo SetParent to SetOwner.

Comment: Good point: **"Only child windows (WS_CHILD style set) have a parent".**   
No, SetParent does not set the owner window, but SetOwner() does this. Plz correct the answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Tom Tom
Thanks for pointing the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer exactly, but this Only ONE gives me the corrent Parent I wanted.
(So I mark it as solution for me)

```
CView* GenericGetActiveView()
{
  // Retrieve Active View
  CView* pActiveView = NULL;    

  CWnd* pWndMain = AfxGetMainWnd();
  if (NULL != pWndMain)
  {
    if (pWndMain->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMDIFrameWnd)))
    {
        // MDI application
        CMDIChildWnd* pChild = ((CMDIFrameWnd*)(pWndMain->MDIGetActive();
        if (pChild)
            pActiveView = pChild->GetActiveView();  
    }
    else if (pWndMain->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CFrameWnd))) 
    {   
        // SDI appllication 
        pActiveView = ((CMainFrame*)pWndMain)->GetActiveView();
    }
    else
        TRACE(_T("Attention no MDI / SDI Main Wnd found!\n"));
  }

  return pActiveView;
}
```

@IInspectable pointed me to this direction in his comment. (MFC has a handle map internally that can easily cause surprising results)